# which carbohydrates are produced in the Calvin Cycle?

Tags: photosynthesis, carbohydrates

I understand the structure of simple carbohydrates (di- and monosaccharides, etc.,) but I'm encountering inconsistent/confusing nomenclature while trying to understand the Calvin Cycle.  One source shows that "the carbohydrate products of the Calvin cycle are three-carbon sugar phosphate molecules, or 'triose phosphates', namely, glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate (G3P)."  Are F6P and E4P also carbohydrates?  Are ALL *n*-carbon sugar phosphate molecules classified as carbohydrates?

Comment: yes they do.  you can delete your comment.

Comment: Sorry typo. I meant F6P and I meant **product**. But think about where I’m coming from. The Calvin cycle may have many intermediates, but it is means to convert three molecules of carbon dioxide to a triose phosphate product. The subsequent conversion of triose to hexose may be part of the dark reactions but is not part of the Calvin Cycle. It just feeds into a linear pathway akin to gluconeogenesis.

Comment: doesn't address my question at all

Comment: If your question is not in the title but about the definition of carbohydrate, you can easily find the answer on the web rather than posting here. Hint: try the Berg chapter on [Carbohydrates](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21139/) and the following [section 11.1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22547/). The phosphate does not contribute to the definition but does not cause an exclusion.